# Gradle multi-module dependecy issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

**Information**

So I have this project structure that looks like this:

> Project root:
>   | Resources-module (uses the packagename: com.derk.application.resources)
>   -+ src 
>   ---+ main 
>   -----+ res 
>   | Core-module (uses the packagename: com.derk.application)
>   -+ src 
>   ---+ main 
>   -----+ src 
>   | Brand-module (uses whatever packagename of the customer domain)

Resources-module contains the res files.
Core contains a git-module that contains code for a code-base we keep updated.
Brand contains build.gradle where I setup the packagename of our customer and bind the main/res directory to the resource-module main/res, and then the main/src to the core-module main/src folder.

Like this:

```
    android.sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"
        res.srcDirs = ["$rootDir/resources-module/src/main/res"]
        java.srcDirs = ["$rootDir/core-module/src/main/java", "src/main/java"]
    }
}
```

I do not wish to alter the Core-module sources under any circumstances without it being pushed up to the master repository, meaing I only make global changes/fixes for all projects that uses core-module. This is why i tried this structure out.

The sourcefiles in the core-module will loads the imports
import com.derk.application.resources.R;
import com.derk.application.resources.BuildConfig;

to handle the resource generated content from gradle/idea

Since Brand-module is due to having packagename changes, I have to use some sort of middlemodule that holds the R and BuildConfig for easy deployment, so that the core-sources indeed never have local modifications.

When i try to refresh gradle for the brand-module, i do not get any issues, and android studio seems to find the R.java and BuildConfig.java just fine in the com.derk.application.resources when I check out the linkage in Android Studio

**HOWEVER**

When I try to run Brand-module, i get:

```
"Execution failed for task ':core-module:compileReleaseJava'."
```

and it now instead shows me:

```
 Error:(20, 39) error: package com.derk.application.resources does not exist
```

even thought I have added

```
 dependencies {
    compile project(':resources-module')
 }
```

to the build.gradle of core-module.

**So the question is:**

How do I setup gradle to handle this kind of cross-module dependency?

Keep in mind, I do not wish to alter the packagename for the core-module imports for each new project I setup, because we get local changes made to a gitmodule that is used for several projects.

/.ps

Currently i can without problem run module resources-module and have the app running, with the static packagename i've chosen for it. But that is also the problem, I want to keep it static, and hence that is why i introduced the third module.

Answer (score 0):

You do that in the wrong way. What you are trying to achive is implementing a normal library module (which you use for every customer). Then you can create a new Module from the type application which uses the shared module. In that case you don't need to mess around with the path of the shared module.

For the case that your shared module is in another directory than the project root you can use this settings.gradle:

```
include ':CustomerX', ':SharedModule'
project(':SharedModule').projectDir = new File('../../some/where/else')
```

If not you can omit the last line.

When you keep a old directory structure you should try using this build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 9
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs       = ['assets']
            res.srcDirs          = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs         = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs    = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            java.srcDirs         = ['src']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // just as example
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
}
```

You customers build.gradle should look e.g. like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("your.keystore")
            storePassword 'pwd1'
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword 'pwd2'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

dependencies {
    // dependencies of the main project
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile project(':SharedModule')
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what resource-module is doing. However, the the core-module consists of Activites and Fragment classes that is also supposted to be shared, so its not just a bunch of library-code in that sense.

Comment: When you do that with the modules also the activities published in the manifest will been merged with the target project.

Comment: What is suggested above does not seem to cover what I am after. The core is using external resources that is expected to always be in the same root directory. I want to make a project that can have a git-module has base for all source code, and another directory that is not a part of the git-module that stores all the resources.

This is not an issues normally, but it becomes an issue when you do not wish to change import paths for the resources for each project.

The issue is that the package containing the resources is not in the buildDirectory of brand-module

Comment: I'm using submodules for that so that works too. However I'm not sure what you really try to do.

Comment: I was hoping the large text above was going to explain that :)

Are your git-submodules actually a project? Cause that is the case here, we are trying to have a project that has the same code everywhere, just a external resource-directory where we quickly can swap out the design we want. There is no way i have found out yet, where you can share the code-base without making local modifications to it.